# Nested sets with Baum and Laravel Commentable: children comments are being inserted without the commentable id and type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, nested

I am trying to achieve multi threaded comments using [Laravel Commentable](https://github.com/RomainLanz/laravel-commentable) which uses Nested Sets with [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum)

I have managed to make the root comments work, however when I reply to a comment, the record in the database gets inserted without `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` so there's no way in knowing whether the reply to that comment is for `App\Post` or `App\Product` because these 2 fields are empty and I can't seem to understand why.

Tables

```
users: id, name, email...
posts: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
comments: id, user_id, parent_id, lft, rgt, depth, commentable_id, commentable_type
```

Routes

```
Route::post('comments/{post}', ['as' => 'comment', 'uses' => 'PostsController@createComment']);
Route::post('comments/{comment}/child', ['as' => 'child-comment', 'uses' => 'PostsController@createChildComment']);
```

Methods in `PostController`

```
public function createComment($id) {

    $post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->where('id', $id)->first();

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = Input::get('comment');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();

    $post->comments()->save($comment);
}

public function createChildComment(Post $post){
    $parent = Comment::find(Input::get('parent_id'));

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = Input::get('child-comment');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->save();
    $comment->makeChildOf($parent);

}
```

View for root comments and children comments

```
<-- This is for root comments --/>
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['comment', $post]]) !!}
@foreach($comments as $comment)

@endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}

<-- This is for children comments --/>
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['child-comment', $comment]]) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="parent_id" value="{{ $comment->id }}"/>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: You need to show us the Post and Comment models as well

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, wouldn't you make the child before you `$comment->save()` the comment, so its in the correct state before it hits the database with `save`.

Edit: Try this:

```
public function createChildComment(Post $post){
    $parent = Comment::find(Input::get('parent_id'));

    $comment = new Comment;
    $comment->body = Input::get('child-comment');
    $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
    $comment->save();
    $comment->makeChildOf($parent);
    $comment->save();

}
```

Currently I'm under the belief that the change that `$comment->makeChildOf($parent)` does would get thrown.

Comment: That gives an error `New node cannot be moved` that's why I am saving before `makeChildOf`

Comment: I've added an extra save, try that, other than that I am out of ideas

Comment: it did not. I got the error `record already exists in the database` so I decided to ditch Baum altogether.